# Trouble with JavaScript Validation on Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I am Trying to validate some input for a login form using JavaScript. From what I can see, everything in the script is correct, but it is not working. I'm sure it's a tiny thing that I've missed, any help would be appreciated.

Note: I am unable to use external libraries.

JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["login"]["username"].value;
        var y = document.forms["login"]["password"].value;
        if (isNaN(x)) && (y === "") {
            alert("Username must be numerical, and password must be entered!");
            return false;
        } else if (isNaN(x)) && (y !== "") {
            alert("Username must be numerical!");
            return false;
        } else if (Number.isInteger(x) == true) && (y === "") {
            alert("Password must be entered!");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<form name="login" method="get">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Customer ID" name="username">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" onclick="return validateForm()" value="Log In" name="button">
    <?php if (isset($errormessage)) { echo $errormessage; } ?>
</form>
```

(I'm very new to web dev, please don't judge too much :p)

Comment: use jquery instead. see https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Comment: Saying that "it is not working" is a bit too broad. Could you elaborate on the actual behaviour ?

Comment: I'm unable to use external libraries for this. Should have specified that.

Comment: I'm getting no response at all.

Password being empty does nothing, same with user being a text input etc

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers :

this line : `var x = document.forms["login"]["username"].value;` will store the value of username as a **string**, even if a numerical value is entered. Now I invite you to test the following line of code :

```
Number.isInteger('12')
```

It will return false.

One of the possible solutions would be to use parseInt on x before using it :

```
var x = parseInt(document.forms["login"]["username"].value);
```

It will still return NaN if a non int parsable value is given, and transform it to an int if the value is parsable.

**Side Note :**

```
parseInt('a') == NaN
parseInt('12') == 12
parseInt('12a') == 12
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You were missing brackets around the conditions for if statements.

```js
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["login"]["username"].value;
        var y = document.forms["login"]["password"].value;
        if ((isNaN(x)) && (y === "")) {
            alert("Username must be numerical, and password must be entered!");
            return false;
        } else if ((isNaN(x)) && (y !== "")) {
            alert("Username must be numerical!");
            return false;
        } else if ((Number.isInteger(x) == true) && (y === "")) {
            alert("Password must be entered!");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

```html
<form name="login" method="get">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Customer ID" name="username">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" onclick="return validateForm()" value="Log In" name="button">
    <?php if (isset($errormessage)) { echo $errormessage; } ?>
</form>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for the most part. The check on the password being empty, but the username being correct isn't working

Comment: @ProbablyDownsy see my answer for this part

Comment: @ProbablyDownsy its because your code is not checking for username being blank. You are only checking if `x isNaN` and if x is an interger. Add in another condition to your code to check for blanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   function validateForm() {
   var x = document.forms["login"]["username"].value;
   var y = document.forms["login"]["password"].value;
   if ( (isNaN(x)) && (y === "")) {
        alert("Username must be numerical, and password must be entered!");
        return false;
    } else if ( (isNaN(x)) && (y !== "")) {
        alert("Username must be numerical!");
        return false;
    } else if ( (Number.isInteger(x) == true) && (y === "")) {
        alert("Password must be entered!");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You have missed some parentheisis in your script please use this code

Answer (score 0):

You've got extra parentheses in your if statement:

```
if (isNaN(x))<- this is closing the conditional and is not required
```

Remove that and it should work:

```
if (isNaN(x) && y === "") {
```

The `else` branches also have this issue, the whole `if` should appear like this:

```
if (isNaN(x) && y === "") {
    alert("Username must be numerical, and password must be entered!");
    return false;
} else if (isNaN(x) && y !== "") {
    alert("Username must be numerical!");
    return false;
} else if (Number.isInteger(x) == true && y === "") {
    alert("Password must be entered!");
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Also, the `isNan` function can be used from `Number` (just like `isInteger`) instead of global, this would make script more consistent :)

Comment: There we go. Thank you very much :)